# C++ destructors causing crash's

Tags: c++, destructor

ok,
so i got a some what intricate program that simulates the uni systems of students, units, and students enrolling in units.

Students are stored in a binary search tree,
Units are stored in a standard list.

Student has a list of Unit Pointers, to store which units he/she is enrolled in
Unit has a list of Student pointers, to store students which are enrolled in that unit.

The unit collections (storing units in a list) as made as a static variable where the main function is, as is the Binary search tree of students.

when its finaly time to close the program, i call the destructors of each. but at some stage, during the destructors on the unit side,

Unhandled exception at 0x002e4200 in ClassAllocation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

UnitCollection destructor:

```
UnitCol::~UnitCol() 
{
    list<Unit>::iterator itr;
    for(itr = UnitCollection.begin(); itr != UnitCollection.end();)
    {
        UnitCollection.pop_front();
        itr = UnitCollection.begin();
    }
}
```

Unit Destructor

```
Unit::~Unit()
{
}
```

now i got the same sorta problem on the student side of things

BST destructors

```
void StudentCol::Destructor(const BTreeNode * r)
{
    if(r!= 0)
    {
        Destructor(r->getLChild());
        Destructor(r->getRChild());
        delete r;
    }
}

StudentCol::~StudentCol()
{
    Destructor(root);
}
```

Student Destructor

```
Student::~Student()
{
}
```

so yeah any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's going on in the BTreeNode destructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `UnitCollection` is `std::list<Unit>` then you don't have to manually remove items - the list itself with destroy contained objects and deallocate the memory in its own destructor.

Take a look at [`std::list` documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html).

I would also suggest that you post complete code - some of your description is contradictory.

Comment: ok so the desturctor will call the unit destructors of all the unit objects in the list?

Comment: Yes, when you put an object into STL container, a *copy* is made into container-managed memory. When container is destructed, that copy is destructed, and memory deallocated.